# Closure of $(0,1)$ with respect to topology $\mathcal{T}$ with sets $U$ s.t. $\forall x\in U$, $(x-ε, x]\subseteq U$ for some $ε > 0$.

Tags: general-topology

As the title explains, I'm trying to solve a problem which asks me to find the closure of $(0,1)$ with respect to  the topology $\mathcal{T}$ which is the family of subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that for every $ x\in U$, there exists $ε>0$ such that $(x-ε, x]\subseteq U$.

I've already proven that $\mathcal{T}$ actually is a topology, but I'm struggling to see what the closure of $(0,1)$ is, much less how to prove it.

I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you think that in this topology, open sets are of the form $(a,b]$

Comment: @TitoEliatron That is not true. In particular, $(0,1)$ is open.

Comment: @jdoe Try to write down what it would mean for a set to be closed in this topology.

Comment: @SmileyCraft But $(0,1)=\bigcup_n (0,1-1/n]$. I meant you can take these intervals as a basis of the topology

Comment: @TitoEliatron Which is exactly why $(0,1)$ is open.

Comment: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) and [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-lower-and-upper-limit-topologies-on-the-real-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure of $(0,1)$ is $(0,1]$. For $1$, every $(1-\epsilon,1]\cap(0,1)\neq \emptyset$, so $1$ is in the closure of $(0,1)$. F0r $a\leq 0$, take any $\epsilon $, then $(a-\epsilon,a]\cap(0,1)= \emptyset$. So $a$ is not in the closure of $(0,1)$. For any $a>1$, say $\epsilon=\frac{a-1}{2}$,  then $(a-\epsilon,a]\cap(0,1)= \emptyset$.